# Creating an m-banking program

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc

Am trying to make a program in Java. I want it to be in such a way when you want to buy something online be it a software or any product you use m-banking like (M-pesa used in Kenya).

When one tries to shop and reaches a point you want to pay you will need to input the amount you want to pay a certain unique number of the product on your phone then the program on the other side should check whether the input money is enough and clear the product as paid. The person buying the product will be given the right to download the product after entering the unique id he/she will be given by the product.

Is it possible to use Java and interact with a program which may be written in another language and then the two programs will be communicating together with the web?

Comment: *"am trying.."*  Try to find your shift key.  When you do, please use it for the 1st letter in each sentence, to help the hapless reader.

Comment: Yes. Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!
There is no problem if you use different languages or technologies. In fact, there are several technical solutions. E.g., you can use a shared database on a Web server that can be accessed by a PHP Web site or a Java application through Sockets...